# Kotlin - Setting up a progress bar with delay

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, coroutine

I am trying to make it so that a progress bar that I put in my edittext field will spin after the user has typed in text.  The progress bar should continue to spin until the user has not typed in any more text for one second.  (If the user keeps typing in text, the progress bar should keep spinning.)  I am using a textWatcher:

```
et_username_username.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {}

        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}

        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

            pb_username_progress_bar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            val updatedText = p0.toString().trim().toLowerCase()

        CoroutineScope(IO).launch{
            
            delay(1000)

            pb_username_progress_bar.visibitlity = View.INVISIBLE
            //updates UI based on firebase database code
}

            }



    })
```

However, when I run this, the coroutine just runs on a different thread every time so the progress bar goes away when the user keeps typing for over a second.
How do I make it so that the progress bar will stay there when the user keeps typing, are coroutines the best way or is there another way??

(It should look a lot like instagram when you create a new account, how it has the spinning progress bar when making username)

Comment: you can use Handler.postDelayed to do something in future on UI thread. or in launch block use pb_username_progress_bar.post() to do work on UI thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code snippet as solution. It will solve your problem.

```
edit_search.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        private var searchFor = ""
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            val searchText = s.toString().trim()
            if (searchText == searchFor)
                return
            searchFor = searchText
            progress_bar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
                delay(1000)
                if (searchText != searchFor)
                    return@launch
                progress_bar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }
        }
    })
```

Happy Coding :)